# C# Windows Store WebView InvokeScriptAsync select drop down

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-async

I am trying to use a WebView control to programmatically select

```html
<select id="ChooseOption">
  <option value="Value1">Option1</option>
  <option value="Value2" selected>Option2</option>
  <option value="Value3">Option3</option>
</select>
```

The code I tried like the following, but it throws an exception HRESULT: 0x80020101 (bad script) on the first InvokeScriptAsync:

```
string[] args =
{
     "var chooseOption = document.getElementById(\"ChooseOption\");"+
     "chooseOption.selectedIndex = 0;"
};
await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", args);
await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "$('#ChooseOption').trigger('change');" });
```

The second one does not work either if I comment out the first InvokeScriptAsync line.  Using the Chrome console I can do the following and it will work:

```
document.getElementById('ChooseOption').selectedIndex;
$('#ChooseOption').trigger('change');
```

What's the right way to do it or can it even be done using the WebView control?

Answer (score 0):

I've not been abled to tried but I think you should add some quotes around the string you are passing to the eval function.

What you are trying to do here can translate to something like this on the webpage:

```
eval(var chooseOption = document.getElementById("ChooseOption");chooseOption.selectedIndex = 0;)
```

Which is not valid.
You probably more want to do something as:

```
eval("var chooseOption = document.getElementById(\"ChooseOption\");chooseOption.selectedIndex = 0;")
```

(Note the leading/trailing quotes)

This translates to the following invocation in C#:

```
string[] args =
{
    "\"var chooseOption = document.getElementById('ChooseOption');"+
 "chooseOption.selectedIndex = 0;\""
};
await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", args);
```

You should just add a leading/trailing \" so your full string will be received as a string by the JS engine.